# how to call methods on Ethernaut level 4 coin flip

Tags: ethers.js

I deployed this contract on rinkeby https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x07BAA5c1fd453009FD5B42a89b846F673c9F11f5 to work on this coinflip challenge https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x4dF32584890A0026e56f7535d0f2C6486753624f and am trying to call the flip method using the loaded web3 library as follows:

```
contract = new ethers.Contract([
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "flip",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ], '0x07BAA5c1fd453009FD5B42a89b846F673c9F11f5')
await contract.methods.flip()
```

but I'm not seeing any changes to `(await contract.consecutiveWins()).toNumber()` from 0, nor am I passing. I tried following the solution https://medium.com/@nicolezhu/ethernaut-lvl-3-walkthrough-how-to-abuse-psuedo-randomness-in-smart-contracts-4cc06bb82570 and at this point I'm just trying to see how I can minimally call the method on the contract to pass these challenges. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use another smart contract to solve this level. In that attacker contract, you can replicate the random flip function that the coin flip contract uses, and use that to 'guess' the flip. Since the random flip function derived pseudorandomness from the blockhash, as long as both the simulated flip (in the attacker contract) and the guess are in the same transaction, you'll be able to correctly guess the flip.